# Is there a size limit for an application on Smart TV?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

We're creating an HTML5 + Javascript app for Samsung Smart TV and are facing the problem that the appliction doesn't load. the size of it is 36 Mb, can this be an issue? Are there any size limits for it?

On emulator everything is ok, the app loads ok

Thanks!

Comment: Well … I can answer one of those questions. If you have two questions, then ask two questions. Don't put them both in one question.

Answer (score 0):

No, the size is not a issue. Try to reset the System of the TV:

1. Go to **Menu**
2. Next **Support**
3. Then **Self Diagnosis**
4. And **Reset**

If it does not resolve the problem, try to simplify the operations of your app, and little by little adding more functions to see what exactly is the problem.